# Assertion error: No value for JSON Path in JUnit test

Tags: java, json, junit, spring-mvc-test

I have written a test and it succeeded before but now I get an AssertionError: No value for JSON Path.

```
@Test
public void testCreate() throws Exception {
    Wine wine = new Wine();
    wine.setName("Bordeaux");
    wine.setCost(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.55));

    new Expectations() {
        {
            wineService.create((WineDTO) any);
            result = wine;
        }
    };

    MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("form", "", "application/json", "{\"name\":\"Bordeaux\", \"cost\": \"10.55\"}".getBytes());
    this.webClient.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/wine").file(jsonFile))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(200))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.name").value("Bordeaux"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.cost").value(10.55));
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value for JSON path: $.name, exception: No results path for $['name']
```

I don't understand what it is not getting or what is missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are asserting that your response contains a field `name` with value `Bordeaux`.

You can print your response using `this.webClient.perform(...).andDo(print())`.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting same problem.

Solution :

Use `.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();`, your response will be a string. My response was:

```
{"url":null,"status":200,"data":{"id":1,"contractName":"Test contract"}
```

When I was trying to do `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)));` there was an error: `java.lang.AssertionError: No value for JSON path: $.id`

To fix it, I did `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.id", is(1)));` and it works because id is a field in data.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely jsonPath interprets the body of your file as a list and this should do the trick (mind the added square brackets as list accessors):

```
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].name").value("Bordeaux"))
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$[0].cost").value(10.55));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after adding `jackson-dataformat-xml` dependency to  my project.

To solve this i had to change my response entity from:

`return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.*STATUS*)`

to

`return ResponseEntity.*status*().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(*your body*)`.

In this way it will work fine, cause you've directly set the `json` as return type for your body.

Answer (score 1):

My return body was `{'status': 'FINISHED', 'active':false}`
and jsonPath did see `status` field, but saw `active`.
The solution: use `jsonPath("$.['status']")` instead of `jsonPath("$.status")`

My assumption: Probably jsonPath ignores some keywords like 'status', etc....

Answer (score -3):

Whatever you are testing for `.name` does not have a property called `name` anymore the error message is pretty clear about that part.

`java.lang.AssertionError: No value for JSON path: $.name, exception: No results path for $['name']`

No one but you knows what you changed to make it go from *working* to *not working* nothing you posted in your question can tell us that.