# springboot Integration test fail when using jsonPath

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsonpath

I have worked with the intergration test in springboot and i have tried to test a get method in my controller.The method is work in postman.However it fail in test which the Json path is not found.

The tested controller method:

```
 @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public Product getproduct(@PathVariable int id){
        return productRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
```

My test code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(OrderController.class)
class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    void getproduct() throws Exception {
/*        RequestBuilder request= MockMvcRequestBuilders.;*/

        mvc.perform(get("/product/{pid}","201")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productName").value("Mobile"));
    }
}
```

result in postman :

```
{
    "pid": 201,
    "productName": "Mobile",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 20000
}
```

error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.productName"
```

Comment: You are using mocks and I see no where behavior being registered for the mocked repositories. No mocking, no result (or at least an empty result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@MockBean` which means you are using mocked repositories **not** real repositories that are connected to a database. As you have registered no behavior on the mocks it will do its default behavior which is, for `Optional` return an empty `Optional`. Which results in `null` being returned thus no body.

I would suggest to rewrite your controller to the following.

```java
@GetMapping("/product/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Product> getproduct(@PathVariable int id){
  return ResponseEntity.of(productRepository.findById(id));
}
```

This will probably make your test fail on the assert for OK as it will now return a 404 (NOT FOUND).

To fix your test register same behavior on the mocked repository.

```java
@Test
void getproduct() throws Exception {
  Product p = /// Create some product
  when(productRepository.findById(201)).thenReturn(Optional.of(p));

  mvc.perform(get("/product/{pid}","201")).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productName").value("Mobile"));
}
```

This will create the behavior you want and will return the product, which you can then assert.

Answer (score 0):

As Marko mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57031787/5907701) the jsonPath *probably* interprets the json body as a list and therefore you can try address the first object in the json body:

```
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].productName").value("Mobile"));
```

Comment: Unluckly,the same error is still occured: java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].productName"

Comment: @user20112858 Have you tried adding contentType header to your mock call so the response is a JSON object: 
`mvc.perform(get("/product/{pid}","201").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))`

Comment: Yes,it also failed sadly